# What does "Had enough in there?" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I am wondering what "Had enough in there?" means in the following sentences:

> I push into the drawing room next door and as I walk through I stop
> short in shock. A figure’s sitting there on the sofa, in the gloom.
> After a moment I recognise it to be Olivia. ‘Oh, hey there,’ I say.
>
> She looks up. Her long legs stick out in front of her, her feet bare.
> ‘Hey.’
>
> ‘**Had enough in there?**’
>
> ‘Yeah.’
>
> ‘Me too,’ I say. ‘You staying up for a bit?’ I ask.
>
> She shrugs. ‘No
> point in going to bed. My room’s right next to *that*.’
>
> As if on cue from the dining room comes a burst of mocking laughter.
> Someone roars: ‘Drink it – drink it all down!’

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 15

Before the actual wedding day, at the rehearsal dinner, Hannah, Charlie's wife, left the dining room where the best man Johnno and the ushers are playing their drinking game (the Irish snap) to find Olivia (the bridesmaid) sitting next door.

In this part, I wonder whether Hannah means "Did you eat a quantity of food in the dining room?" or perhaps, "Are you sick and tired being in the dining room, with all the noises from the drinking game?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the second one.

"I've had enough" means literally "I have had as much (food, drink or of an experience) as I want", but it is quite commonly used in the sense of "I can't bear a situation any longer".